# Is it possible embed gist url in swift uikit?

Tags: swift, uikit, gist

I would like to embed gist url in swift uikit (mobile) like in this picture

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

I tried to use some styles but they are not working fully functional

Comment: Actually, I dont share the code here, I have to share the picture of it to make it more understandable for the people who want to answer the question. So the code has nothing to do with it, it is just the picture visualization

Comment: Please clarify your question and what problem you are trying to solve. For example, are you trying to display code within a web page or are you trying to `syntax highlight` code? There are many libraries available that support GitHub Gists, perhaps review a few and then update your question with details.